# Java - Calculate File Compression

Tags: java, file, compression, zip, rar

Is there a way to get the possible compression ratio of a file just reading it?
You know, some files are more compressible then others... my software has to tell me the percentage of possible compression of my files.
e.g.
`Compression Ratio: 50%` -> I can save 50% of my file's space if I compress it
`Compression Ratio: 99%` -> I can save only 1% of my file's space if I compress it

Comment: Without touching it. Does that include reading? I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that.

Comment: What API are you using? Please provide more details.

Comment: What do you mean by *without touching it*? If you mean *without reading the whole file* then no there isn't. If we are allowed to read the file then obviously **yes**. Odd question!!

Comment: sorry, maybe it was not clear... i meant "just reading it" :) i've no idea of which APIs are available, this is a "theoric" question

Comment: The best you can do is to compress some of the file (if its large) and use this as an estimate. If its small, the estimate will be poor unless you compress the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to work on information theory. There are two theory about information theory field:

1. According to Shannon, one can compute entropy (i.e. compressed size) of a source by using it's symbol probabilities. So, smallest compression size defined by an statistical model which produces symbol probabilities at each step. All algorithms use that approach implicitly or explicitly to compress data. Look that [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) for more details.
2. According to Kolmogorov, smallest compression size can be found by finding smallest possible program which produces the source. In that sense, it cannot be compute-able. Some program partially use that approach to compress data (e.g. you can write a small console application which can produce 1 million digits of PI instead of zipping that 1 million digits of PI).

So, you can't find compressed size without evaluating actual compression. But, if you need an approximation, you can rely on Shannon's entropy theory and build a simple statistical model. Here is a very simple solution:

1. Compute order-1 statistics for each symbol in the source file.
2. Calculate entropy by using those statistics.

Your estimation will be more or less same as ZIP's default compression algorithm (deflate). [Here](http://encode.ru/threads/347-seg_file) is a more advanced version of same idea (be aware it uses lots of memory!). It actually uses entropy to determine blocks boundaries to apply segmentation for dividing file into homogeneous data.

Answer (score 2):

First, this will depend largely on the compression method you choose.  And second, I seriously doubt it's possible without computation of time and space complexity comparable to actually doing the compression. I'd say your best bet is to compress the file, keeping track of the size of what you've already produced and dropping/freeing it (once you're done with it, obviously) instead of writing it out.

To actually do this, unless you really want to implement it yourself, it'll probably be easiest to use the [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) class, in particular the [`Deflater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) class and its `deflate` method.

Comment: well i've never studied the file compression argument, i've just few ideas on the methods... i guess i would use classic archive formats like .zip or .rar

Comment: about the time complexity, i know that it would be proportional to the compression itself but surely faster! i don't want a tool that makes compressions, i want just an analysis of my files

Comment: @Oneiros At the very minimum, you'll need to look at every byte of the file and keep track of how many of each there are.  You *may* be able to get away with stopping there, finding the entropy, and using that to calculate a *theoretical* best compression. But I doubt that will be significantly faster.

Comment: thank you, your explanation is very useful :) well, i think i should find a good speed-precision compromise

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without examining the file.  The only thing you can do is have an approximate ratio by file extension based on statistics gathered from a relative large sample by doing actual compression and measuring.  For example a statistical analysis will likely show that .zip, .jpg are not heavily compressible, but files like .txt and .doc might be heavily compressible.

The results of this will be for rough guidance only and will probably be way off in some cases as there's absolutely no guarantee of compressible-ness by file extension.  The file could contain anything no matter what the extension say it may or may not be.

UPDATE:  Assuming you can examine the file then you can use the `java.util.zip` APIs to read the raw file and compress it and see what the before/after difference is.

Comment: i'm sorry, my question was not clear: of course i am allowed to examinate the file

Comment: My answer to the update: it doesn't help me because i want to make just an analysis of my files... imagine this scenario: i have a folder with a lot of big files (of any type) on my drive. i need a tool that helps me to optimize the space of my drive by telling me "ok, these files could have a good compression, zip them" but i don't want to wait the time needed by the whole compression, i don't need the compression process! it would be a stupid tool if it compresses all the files and then gives me an analysis of it...

Comment: Then refer to my original answer.  Alternatively if the file is very large compress the first say 1MB of it to get a rough approximation of the compression.